# mySQL - SELECT using JOIN, or a nested SELECT (sub-select)?

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join, nested-select

I am trying to write a SELECT in mySQL (and PHP) that will retrieve all the rows in "Images" table that were not ranked yet by a certain user.

Those are my tables:

Table: **Images**

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| Index     | Rank_Good| Rank_OK   | Rank_Bad |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------
| 201       | 2        | 9         | 28       |
| 202       | 11       | 20        | 39       |
| 203       | 36       | 14        | 7        |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Table2: **WhoAlreadyClickedImg** (has no index)

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| ImageIndex | UserWhoRankedIt | RankGiven |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 202        | 87              | OK        |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 202        | 93              | Bad       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 204        | 93              | Good      |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 203        | 94              | Bad       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Every time a user rank an image, the table "Images" is updated and a row is added to "WhoAlreadyClickedImg" table. (this table has no index)

for example, if the user ranked image index 202 with "ok", then the col "Rank_OK" will be updated to (+1) and then, a new row will be added to the "WhoAlreadyClickedImg" table:

**ImageIndex: 201** |  **UserWhoRankedIt: (the used session id)**  |   **RankGiven: OK**

i want to build a select that will not show the same image twice to a user who already ranked it.

for example, if I'm user "93", the only image that the select will bring is "203"

**UPDATED:**

This is the query i'm using (by @eamonn):

> SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Index NOT IN 
>       (SELECT ImageIndex FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg WHERE UserWhoRankedIt = 93);

but I get an error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index NOT IN (SELECT ImageIndex FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg WHERE UserWhoRankedIt' at line 1**

### I checked my system:

- Storage Engine: InnoDB
- MySQL db version: 5.5.33-29.3
- both tables now have Index, int(11), defined as PRIMARY, auto_increment

maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you dump the SQL for your setup so I can have a fiddle in a local environment to see where things are going wrong? Pastebin is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, this should work:

```
SELECT Images.Index 
       FROM Images 
       WHERE Images.Index NOT IN 
             (
                SELECT WhoAlreadyClickedImg.ImageIndex 
                     FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg 
                     WHERE WhoAlreadyClickedImg.UserWhoRankedIt = 93
             );
```

Remember to add the names of the tables before the name of the column.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Index NOT IN 
(SELECT ImageIndex FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg WHERE UserWhoRankedIt = 93);`

Simple subquery.

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work. I even tried adding an index to the WhoAlreadyClickedImg table (as @e4c5 suggested). This is the error it gives me:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index NOT IN (SELECT ImageIndex FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg WHERE UserWhoRankedIt' at line 1"

Answer (score 1):

Well the column name Index is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You should change the name of the Index column to Id or MainIndex. See this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Another option is to use the table name inside the select query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Images.Index NOT IN (SELECT ImageIndex FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg WHERE UserWhoRankedIt = 93);
```

I think you should rename your column since that minimizes the chances of errors in SQL statements.

Comment: got to a lot of rows in the table that is being called by the sub-select. and it is VERY slow sometimes and sometimes it is ok. (when I test it and empty this table it is always fast) - any suggestion? maybe JOIN would be better or is JOIN not the solution and the select is simply done wrong?

Comment: You should add an index on these columns: Index, ImageIndex and UserWhoRankedIt. It should improve performance of the sql query

Comment: You mean that If I add an index to the "WhoAlreadyClickedMyImg" table, EVEN IF I TOTALY IGNORE IT in my query, it will help the speed? How?!

Comment: And also - what do you mean by saying "add index to all those three columns"? You mean - define each one as Index?

Comment: Well, yes. Add an index to all three columns. Most database administration tools such as phpMyAdmin support adding indexes. When you add an index to a column, the database server stores the contents of that column in a special format which reduces the time needed to search the column